# NodeJS + Nodemailer - attempting to implement password reset but keep getting an error

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I am building a Node.js app and I am attempting to build a reset password function.  When I am attempting to actually reset a password, I keep getting this error "Received non-function type in catchAsync: undefined"

I can send a reset link, click on it and get taken to the reset password page.  But when attempting to submit the reset password I get the above error.

Here is the code I have so far:

My user Routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');

(filename is found in the relevant controllers file)
const users = require('../controllers/users');

const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');

router.route('/forgot-password')
    .get(users.renderForgotPasswordForm)
    .put(catchAsync(users.handleForgotPassword));


router.route('/reset/:token')
    .get(users.renderResetPasswordForm)
    .put(catchAsync(users.handlePasswordReset));


module.exports = router;
```

This is my catchAsync code:

```
module.exports = func => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        func(req, res, next).catch(next);
    }
}
```

And finally this is the controller where I am attempting the reset password:

```
module.exports.handleResetPassword = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { token } = req.params;
    const user = await User.findOne({ passwordResetToken: token, passwordResetExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } });

    if (!user) {
        req.flash('error', 'Token is invalid or has expired.');
        return res.redirect('/forgot-password');
    }

    if (req.body.password === req.body.confirm) {
        await user.setPassword(req.body.password); // using passportLocalMongoose method
        user.passwordResetToken = null;
        user.passwordResetExpires = null;
        await user.save();

    } else {
        req.flash('error', 'Passwords do not match.');
        return res.redirect(`/reset/${token}`);
    }

    await emailController.sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail(user);

    req.flash('success', 'Your password has been reset.');
    res.redirect('/');
};
```

I cant see what it is I am doing wrong and would appreciate any insight.

I have put in console logs which suggest the functions are being passed correctly, however when attempt the handleResetPassword I get the error.

I have tried matching passwords and mismatching passwords and still get the error.